# How can I know if an achievement is completed in android?

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm developing an android app with achievements. Is it possible to know if the achievement is unlocked (or if the goal is reached on incremental ones)?

I've found solutions for old implementations which use `Games.Achievements` and add a callback function, but it is deprecated. This is the code I'm using for unlocking my achievements:

```
Games.getAchievementsClient(MyActivity.this, acct).unlockImmediate(my_achievement_id));
```

I'd like to add a listener to know if after the execution of my code the achievement is unlocked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved using `load` method:

```
Games.getAchievementsClient(MyActivity.this, acct).load(true).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AnnotatedData<AchievementBuffer>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(AnnotatedData<AchievementBuffer> achievementBufferAnnotatedData) {
            AchievementBuffer buffer = achievementBufferAnnotatedData.get();
            Achievement achievement;
            Iterator<Achievement> iterator = buffer.iterator();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                achievement = iterator.next();
                if (achievement.getAchievementId().equals(myAchievementId) && achievement.getState() == Achievement.STATE_UNLOCKED) {
                    // The achievement is unlocked
                } else {
                    // The achievement is locked
                }
            }
        }
});
```